# Combining 3 tables into one table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables that have the exact same columns, the only difference is the data in those columns. I was wondering if (and how) I should merge the columns into one table. I know that the data would be distinguishable by a boolean value if you merge two tables, but can the same be done with three tables?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the columns and datatypes are the same, then you can use a `UNION ALL` query.

```
select col1, col2, 'table1' as src
from table1
union all
select col1, col2, 'table2' as src
from table2
union all
select col1, col2, 'table3' as src
from table3
```

This version will include any duplicate records, if you don't want duplicates then you can use `UNION` which will remove any duplicated records.

If the datatypes are not the same, then you will need to convert the data to be of the same type.

Comment: I'd add a column to show which source table the data came from, particularly if this is going to be used to feed a "merge" table of some sort.

Comment: @AaronBertrand edited, thanks. I usually include that value for those reasons.